# how to set default for multi value options

Tags: python, python-click

I want something like this:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option("-r", "--range", nargs=2, type=int, default=(1,2), show_default=True)
def scale(range):
   print "scale to %d - %d" % range

if __name__ == '__main__':
   scale()
```

But the default value for the option of multi values doesn't work here. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now [implemented in master](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/commit/c8d3300a2467d3a017aac1d24a92cb254ce921fe) and will be generally available when v3 is released.  It will work as you've written, by passing an iterable to `default=`.  `nargs=` and `multiple=True` are supported, individually and [together](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/commit/c8d3300a2467d3a017aac1d24a92cb254ce921fe#diff-2e8fd1786cf8cbb1200e536fac392663R35).

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--foo', default=[23, 42], type=click.FLOAT, multiple=True)
def cli(foo):
    for item in foo:
        click.echo(item)

@click.command()
@click.option('--arg', default=((1, 2), (3, 4)), nargs=2, multiple=True, type=click.INT)
def cli(arg):
    for item in arg:
        click.echo('<%d|%d>' % item)
```